# numpy divide row by row sum

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

How can I divide a numpy array row by the sum of all values in this row?

This is one example. But I'm pretty sure there is a fancy and much more efficient way of doing this:

```
import numpy as np
e = np.array([[0., 1.],[2., 4.],[1., 5.]])
for row in xrange(e.shape[0]):
    e[row] /= np.sum(e[row])
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.83333333]])
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Method #1: use `None` (or `np.newaxis`) to add an extra dimension so that broadcasting will behave:

```
>>> e
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  5.]])
>>> e/e.sum(axis=1)[:,None]
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.83333333]])
```

Method #2: go transpose-happy:

```
>>> (e.T/e.sum(axis=1)).T
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.83333333]])
```

(You can drop the `axis=` part for conciseness, if you want.)

Method #3: (promoted from Jaime's comment)

Use the `keepdims` argument on `sum` to preserve the dimension:

```
>>> e/e.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.83333333]])
```

Comment: I don't see how you can drop the `axis=1`.  Without the `axis` argument, `sum()` returns the sum of all the values in the array.

Comment: In numpy 1.7 there is a `keepdims` argument that lets you do `e/e.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I didn't say you could drop the `1` part, I said you could drop the `axis=` part.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Could you explicitly explain the `[:,None]` notation? I see the change it makes, but don't get the coding convention.

Comment: @Michael `newaxis` is an alias for `None`, which is a bit more semantically understandable http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 6):

You can do it mathematically as [image].

Here, `E` is your original matrix and `D` is a diagonal matrix where each entry is the sum of the corresponding row in `E`. If you're lucky enough to have an invertible `D`, this is a pretty mathematically convenient way to do things.

In numpy:

```
import numpy as np

diagonal_entries = [sum(e[row]) for row in range(e.shape[0])]
D = np.diag(diagonal_entries)
D_inv = np.linalg.inv(D)
e = np.dot(e, D_inv)
```

Comment: While this answer might be correct, using for loop isn't the way to go about it. It is not completely vectorised. Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use reshape method of numpy as follows:

```
e = np.array([[0., 1.],[2., 4.],[1., 5.]])
e/=np.sum(e, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
e

array([[0.        , 1.    ],
       [0.33333333, 0.66666667],
       [0.16666667, 0.83333333]])
```