# handing 2D array data in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the below code in google colab, but not goes well.

```
logits = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
ret = logits
sum_array = np.sum(logits, axis = 1)

rows = len(logits)
cols = len(logits[0])

for i in range(rows):
  for j in range(cols):
      ret[i, j] = ret[i, j] / sum_array[i]

print("---------------Final output------------------------------------")
ret
```

the result is like below.
[image]

my intention is to get result like below(divide each row by sum of all element in row).

```
logits = 
[ 
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
]

results = 
[ 
  [0/(1+2+3), 1/(1+2+3), 2/(1+2+3)],
  [3/(4+5+6), 4/(4+5+6), 5/(4+5+6)],
  [6/(7+8+9), 7/(7+8+9), 8/(7+8+9)],
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy divide row by row sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202348/numpy-divide-row-by-row-sum)

Comment: The explanation and the example code do not match.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. You might want to edit your post. The sums in the last cell are incorrect.

```
logits = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

dividors = [[sum(row)] for row in logits]

ret = logits/dividors
```

Test:

```
print(ret)
```

Output:

```
[[0.         0.33333333 0.66666667]
 [0.25       0.33333333 0.41666667]
 [0.28571429 0.33333333 0.38095238]]
```

Comment: The reason the original code fails is because it started with `ret = logits`, which fixes the `dtype` to `int`, not `float`. This causes the division result to become 0 for all elements.

Comment: oof you're right. I didn't notice that. Thanks. In that case op will just need to specify the type of logits to float. I'm trynna tag op but I don't have the characters of their name. Please tag them so they see this.